# Image links open in new window or iframe if possible

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hyperlinks

Is it possible to make image links open in a new window or possible iframe?

Annoyingly they open in the same window and if you forget and close you take yourself out of bicyles.stackexchange.

i know from an simple coding point of view adding target="_blank" to the url will allow this but can it be implemented on just bicycles se or would the main SE have to implement this, in which case it may well be question for the main meta.se

An example would be

Open in current window : Bike Image

Open in new window : Bike Image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a feature request for the larger Stack Exchange network. It's not something that we have control over on this site.

There was [a request raised for this on the network meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/make-links-posted-by-users-open-in-a-new-window), but it doesn't look like it was well received.

Comment: I just had a read through, i already knew about ctr / click new window, however it just feels normal for new tab to open, even more so if the link refers to a completely different website. From a web design point of view, forcing people away from your site is the last thing you want. I guess i will have to live with it, again highly annoying as it would take less than a minute for SE to implement the option  PS @jimchristie  your link is broken it contains %20https:// unfortunately the option to edit isn't available.